# Android 4.3 build error

Tags: android, build

I found some same errors posted on other forums but no answer found yet for fixing this.

Running on my newly installed Ubuntu 12.10,

```
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:22097: error 12: Class
android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage changed static qualifier
prebuilts/sdk/api/18.txt:22054: error 9: Removed public constructor SmsMessage()
prebuilts/sdk/api/18.txt:22055: error 9: Removed public method    
android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.calculateLength
prebuilts/sdk/api/18.txt:22056: error 9: Removed public method  
android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.calculateLength
prebuilts/sdk/api/18.txt:22057: error 9: Removed public method  
android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.createFromPdu
prebuilts/sdk/api/18.txt:22058: error 9: Removed public method  
android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody
prebuilts/sdk/api/18.txt:22059: error 9: Removed public method 
android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress
prebuilts/sdk/api/18.txt:22060: error 9: Removed public method 
android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.getEmailBody
prebuilts/sdk/api/18.txt:22061: error 9: Removed public method  
android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.getEmailFrom
..
..
..
```

It's obviously that the gsm.SmsMessage has some unknown issue with the building environment.

I tried to switch my java version from 1.7 to 1.6. But it still does not work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: anyone? i really dont know why this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors were resolved by re-downloading the source code.

So if any of you encountered the same error, I would suggest you to re-download the source.

The error should be gone.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried the first answer, which didn't work. I'll try yours.

Comment: This may have been working for the Original Poster, but the root of this problem is most of the time the version mismatch in java, javac or javadoc versions. Unfortunately Google's documentation doesn't state that also javadoc must be 1.6, that is the root of this problem - the api specifications generated by javadoc 1.7 and 1.8 are different from the official versions provided by the sources. This is why the building process complains for the updated api.

Answer (score 17):

In my case, the problem was caused by `javadoc` from OpenJDK7, when I should be using JDK6 (Oracle).

As of now, JDK7 is needed to build the master branch of Android, and JDK6 for building Gingerbread (2.3) through Kitkat (4.4.4).

If you have several JDKs, make sure you select the right one for java/javac/javadoc. You can use these commands:

`$ sudo update-alternatives --config java`

`$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac`

`$ sudo update-alternatives --config javadoc`

Output example for selecting `java` (first command above):

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java          1         manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          2         manual mode
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: Joon's answer also help.

Comment: You are my hero

Answer (score 5):

After an extensive search I finally found source of this error here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/Xw34n7PQJsA/kieneMNt4LkJ. If re-downloading the source does not work for you make sure java,javac and javadoc are using version 1.6 not 1.7. Apparently javadoc 1.7 has some sort of wonkyness that's triggered by the android AOSP build process. That in turn causes weird errors with apicheck usaully this one.

Comment: May need to completely delete all previous output after switching to Java 1.6. Otherwise the corrupted files aren't always rebuilt. beyond that I don't think I can help here. There are various support forums which maybe of assistance. There maybe something else weird about your setup or code.

Comment: I'm trying to re-download and re-build .. let's see

Comment: This one works.  Change javadoc to Oracle 1.6
`sudo update-alternatives --config javadoc`

Answer (score 3):

I could fix it after touching the files to rebuild them.

```
$ touch frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.java
$ touch frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/android/telephony/gsm/SmsMessage.java

$ make
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed the source code in Android, you will need to issue "make update-api" before "make otapackage" to update api changes that you have made

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly with javadoc which is 1.7 but what is really wrong is that after changing it to 1.6 from oracle and "make clean" it doesn't help. Removing and downloading sources helps. I was looking for some make target like "make distclean" or "make mrproper" to avoid redownloading sources which is time consuming. I found nothing.